# Content hiding behind left side menu

Tags: menu, css-position, containers

The content of my webpage is going behind the side menu I have positioned to the left.I want the menu to be fixed however whenever I do so the content hides behind the menu to the left. Any help would be much appreciated. (Apologies for formatting, new to the site.)

.menu {

```
padding-top: 150px;




height: 100%;




width: 170px;




background-color: white;




float: left;




display: table;





position: fixed;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed elements are no longer within the page flow, they act in the same way as an absolute positioned element. Chris Coyier has a really good explanation about the differences in positioning http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

In order for your body content to stop flowing behind the fixed property, you need to create a container (if one does not exist yet) that all of the body content resides in, except of course the nav/menu bar. You then apply a padding-left to the main body content equal so the width of the fixed element so that the main body content is **always** padded away from the left of the browser.

Fixed elements **don't** affect the flow and positioning of elements and position:relative on a parent container has no affect on a fixed element.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, very clear and easy to follow information that helped fix my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately requires a reputation of 15, would otherwise.